# How to have a button's handler copy itself into a different array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Essentially I have two menus - one for the default buttons, and one for buttons that were already clicked. They should act as follows: The user opens menu A, which is populated with 6 buttons. They select one of the buttons, and that button is now copied to menu B. The selected button should now act and appear identically in both menu A and menu B. I haven't quite figured out how to do this without getting some kind of circular reference, infinite loop, or getting a "x.render() is not a function" error.

Here's the function I call in menu A to generate the buttons originally (which works correctly, except where I push it to the other menu):

```
function btn(txt, font) {
var temp = {};
temp.xtype = "button";
temp.text = txt;
temp.handler = function (btn) {
    btn.up("button").menu.style = font;
    btn.up("button").down("#menuB").items.items.push(new btn(txt, font));
};
return temp;
}
```

Comment: what's your html?

Comment: @SergChernata The html for the button itself is what gets passed as the txt variable - sorry should've made that more clear

Comment: Just to add to that in case it's not clear, in menu A I can do:
items: [new btn("randomhtml", "courier")]
and everything renders correctly

Answer (score 0):

Can you separate all of the non-menu changing parts of your handlers, like so:

```
const handlers = {
    firstHandler(btn) {
        doWhateverFirstButtonDoes(btn);
    },
    secondHandler() { ...
};
```

Then, can you separate the "add to second menu" function for all buttons on the first menu:

```
addToSecondMenu = function(btn) {
   // I'm not clear where txt/font come from, but if you have the btn
   // presumably you can get the right txt/font for it
   btn.up("button").menu.style = font;
   btn.up("button").down("#menuB").items.items.push(new btn(txt, font));
}
```

Then, when you bind your first menu, you can combine the two:

```
firstMenuButon.onClick = function(e) {
    handlers.firstHander(e.target);
    addToSecondMenu(e.target);
}
```

Then, in your second menu, you can do the same thing, only with an `addToFirstMenu`:

```
addToFirstMenu = function(btn) {
   // I'm not clear where txt/font come from, but if you have the btn
   // presumably you can get the right txt/font for it
   btn.up("button").menu.style = font;
   btn.up("button").down("#menuA").items.items.push(new btn(txt, font));
}

firstMenuButonOnMenuB.onClick = function(e) {
    handlers.firstHander(e.target);
    addToFirstMenu(e.target);
}
```

Although I can't say for certain without seeing all of your code, by separating the "what the button really does" logic from the "adding and removing buttons from menus" logic you should be able to avoid the type of issues you described.

Comment: I can try to spin something off that logic that may work, but the reason that won't work straight up is because there are 6 default buttons with infinite possible user defined 'txt's.

Comment: There's only 6 texts at once though right (or maybe 12)?  Can you just save them in a `const textForButtons = {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}`?

Comment: No, there are 6 default buttons in menu A, with the ability for the user to define and add infinite buttons to menu A. Menu B starts empty, and can be added to only by clicking on a button in A.

Comment: At any given moment menu A has a finite number of buttons.  The text for those buttons can be stored in an object or array, no matter how many buttons there are.